# Correctly freeing pointer to linked list

Tags: c, malloc, c99

After more than 10 years of having the luxury of using garbage collected languages, I am returning to C99 and obviously I am having difficulties with memory management.

I have a linked list consisting of stack items and a type `Stack` which points to the address of the first element of this list.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct StackItem
{
    int head;
    struct StackItem* next;
} StackItem;

typedef StackItem** Stack;

StackItem* makeStackItem (int head)
{
    StackItem* a = (StackItem*) malloc (sizeof (StackItem) );
    a->head = head;
    a->next = (StackItem*) 0;
    return a;
}

Stack makeStack ()
{
    Stack stack = (Stack) malloc (sizeof (StackItem*) );
    *stack = (StackItem*) 0;
    return stack;
}

void pushStack (StackItem* item, Stack stack)
{
    item->next = *stack;
    *stack = item;
}

void freeStack (Stack stack)
{
    StackItem* current = *stack;
    StackItem* next;
    while (current != 0)
    {
        next = current->next;
        free (current);
        current = next;
    }
    free (stack);
}

int main ()
{
    Stack stack = makeStack ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        pushStack (makeStackItem (i), stack);
    printf ("Here be dragons.\n");
    freeStack (stack);
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Are the first lines of `makeStack` and `makeStackItem` sensible and
   necessary?
2. Is the last line of `freeStack` sensible and necessary?
3. Once `main` returns, have I freed all the memory previously
   allocated?
4. How can I see whether I have memory leaks or not?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: on your 4th question I'd advise checking out [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: casting malloc is discouraged. I personally hate hiding indirections in typedef's, it makes the code less readable ( typedef StackItem** Stack; )

Comment: Charlie beat me to it, but here's why - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: In type declarations, asterisks bind to the *right*, and should be spaced to emphasize this: `StackItem *stack`, *not* `StackItem* stack`.  (Many people say just the opposite. They are wrong.)

Comment: Thank you everybody. I will look into this valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the first lines of makeStack and makeStackItem sensible and necessary? `yes except for the casting malloc issue`

Is the last line of freeStack sensible and necessary? `yes`

Once main returns, have I freed all the memory previously allocated? `yes`

How can I see whether I have memory leaks or not? `use valgrind`

```
I would toss the casts of 0 too.
```

Comment: Just to get you right: Basically replace `(sometype*) malloc ()` with `malloc ()` and `(sometype*) 0` with `0`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would suggest.

Comment: `(sometype*)0` is necessary when (and *only* when) you are passing a null pointer as one of the anonymous arguments to a variadic or unprototyped function.  In that solitary context, a bare `0` does not convert to a null pointer when you want it to.  The only time you are ever likely to encounter this issue is with the [`execl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) family, whose last argument must always be `(char *)0`.  Note also that using `NULL` *does not* get you out of needing the explicit cast in this context, because `#define NULL 0` is a legitimate thing for `<stddef.h>` to do.

Comment: @Zack is that because of when sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *) ?

Comment: Yes, plus other more exotic possibilities, such as the CPU making a distinction between "address" and "data" registers and the ABI requiring pointer arguments to go in the former (M68K most famously; still a live possibility in the modern day), or the bit pattern for a null pointer not being all-bits-zero (very unlikely to come up nowadays; dim memory that some of the Burroughs minis did this, not sure)